# Can I have Parallel Object Recognition in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium Webdriver, and I want to verify that everything has loaded in a browser (Chrome as it happens). The browser main window will have 10 or more objects loading inside it (each within their own iframe). I want to ascertain as quickly as possible that each object has loaded, then carry on with the rest of the test. Is it possible to use the C# Parallel.foreach construct to speed things up here, or do I have to check in series.

```
Parallel.ForEach(loop, f=>
{
    try
    {
         _customObject.MethodCheckingForAnIWebElement(f, AnArrayWithSomeInfo[f]);
    }
    catch (Exception e) { Console.WriteLine("Throw:" + f + ":" + e.Message); }
});
```

The code snippet above is throwing f-1 *Element is not attached to the page object* errors, which is making me think that I just cannot do this approach.
To be clear, each call, I will do something like

```
_webDriver.SwitchTo().Frame(aFrame)
_webDriver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(some.property));
```

Apologies if I have missed some obvious documentation on this!

Comment: Answer seems to be no. :)

Answer (score -1):

The answer appears to be as I suspected, in the threading model we have for Selenium WebDriver we can't process in parallel. Hence the consistent attachment error. See also [Can Selenium use multi threading in one browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30808606/can-selenium-use-multi-threading-in-one-browser)

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14112736)

Comment: Thank you for your review. How do you think my answer could be more complete?

Comment: The answer is rather short and without code. It could have been an update to your Question.

Comment: What code could be added when there is no code which can do the job in question?

Comment: I added a link to another Multi thread question on Selenium as it seems to support my answer.