# Locating a form with Mechanize in ruby

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, mechanize

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'mechanize'

agent = Mechanize.new

page = agent.get('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/')
forms = page.forms.first
pp form
```

I am trying to locate the form to login to the instagram website. I cannot seem to get mechanize to locate the form even though it should be the only one on the page. When I pretty print the page I get back blank output.

Answer (score 1):

This page uses Javascript to render the form, which mechanize doesn't run. If you want to see what a page looks like without Javascript, you can open it with the lynx browser.

Selenium can be used instead. After installing a driver such as for chrome (see [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver)), the API is pretty similar:

```
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
driver.navigate.to "https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/"
first_form = driver.find_elements(css: "form")[0]
```

Comment: If I use the selenium webdriver to authenticate can I use nokogiri to send further requests to the server and parse them while maintaining my login session? Trying to use a multithreaded approach to scraping.

Comment: @BenGitter although it can be run without GUI using the `headless` gem, and also wrapped into a Thread so as to not block the main thread, according to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30808606/can-selenium-use-multi-threading-in-one-browser) the driver is not thread safe, so your best bet would be to launch _multiple drivers_ to run parallel tests. Haven't used it myself, but [Selenium Grid](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/07_selenium_grid.jsp) seems a promising tool.