# JMeter Selenium test always using 1 thread

Tags: jmeter

I want to start testing my JMeter scripts on my website using selenium,

If I follow the [tutorial](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-webdriver-sampler) it state that it works **only** using 1 thread

> DO NOT change the "Thread Group" values. They must all be set to 1.

Do I have a limit of running selenium test using 1 user per computer at a time?

I found also [answers about selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30808606/can-selenium-use-multi-threading-in-one-browser) that it can be done, but not recommended. just want to make sure it shouldn't be done and keep executing 1 thread in JMeter + Selenium test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking into [Web Driver Tutorial](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverTutorial/):

> Note: It is NOT the intention of this project to replace the [HTTP Samplers](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) included in JMeter. Rather it is meant to compliment them by measuring the end user load time.

So it is recommended to create the main load using JMeter's HTTP Request samplers and use one (or several) WebDriver Samplers to measure scripts execution time, rendering speed, etc.

Also pay attention to the quote from the [10 Minute Guide](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverTutorial/#10-Minute-Guide)

> Each browser consumes a significant amount of resources, and a limit should be placed on how many browsers the reader should create.
>
> From experience, the number of browser (threads) that the reader creates should be limited by the following formula:
>
> ```
> C = N + 1
> ```
>
> where C = Number of Cores of the host running the test
>   and N = Number of Browser (threads)
>
> eg, if the current reader's host has 4 cores, the formula would yield:
>
> ```
> 4 = 3 + 1
> ```
>
> meaning that the script should have a MAXIMUM of 3 threads.

Also check out the memory footprint for a single browser accessing your application.

So theoretically you can kick off one browser per each CPU core after 1st and allocate around 1 GB of RAM for your browser (this may vary depending on how "heavy" your page is.

Check out [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-10-questions-answered) for more details on Selenium and JMeter integration.