# Need to File Lock Selenium Webdriver When Threading?

Tags: python, multithreading, selenium, web-scraping

I have a lot of threads booting up phantomJS or Chromedriver like this:

```
 Driver= webdriver.PhantomJS('C:\phantomjs.exe',desired_capabilities=dcap, service_args=service_args)
```

or

```
Driver= webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

This might seem like a stupid question but I'm trying to track down the reason for threads to be silently failing infrequently and rarely and this is the only bit of code I can see without much exception handling.

If I have 100+ threads running this at about the same time could that cause an issue? I've only ever used file locking if I'm actually modifying something. There's no need for it when multiple threads are just using the same file for a webdriver... right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to: [Is Selenium WebDriver thread safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28093347/is-selenium-webdriver-thread-safe)

> WebDriver is not thread-safe. Having said that, if you can serialize
>   access to the underlying driver instance, you can share a reference in
>   more than one thread. This is not advisable. You /can/ on the other
>   hand instantiate one WebDriver instance for each thread.

... which suggests that the more concurrent your tasks, and the less tolerant you are of failures, the more you need to stick to a single driver instance per thread. I don't think file locking will be any use here.

Another issue is that running browser instances on a single machine is relatively expensive, so you'll be lucky to be able to run 10 instances / threads without degrading performance.

This arrangement can work fine, but you'll never be able to run 100+ of threads concurrently (it's impossible to do that in practice anyway). 5 or 10 should be OK, and I doubt your throughput will be any less.

If your needs are greater than that, you're probably better off using Selenium Grid and multiple nodes.