# Selenium Threads: How to open the same browser in multiple threads? for the purposes of each browser using a unique proxy

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, selenium, multiprocessing

```python
import threading

def rand_function1():
  #random actions

def rand_function2():
  #random actions

def main()
  rand_function1
  rand_function2
  return


if __name__ == '__main__':
    url_list = "https://www.rand_urls.com/"
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    for t in range(10):
        t = threading.Thread(target=main)
        t.start()
```

I have this simple program that I am trying to open urls using 10 Firefox web drivers. However, all it does it use one browser and continue to cycle though urls thought that individual browser. I will be using a unique proxies for each browser so opening tabs wont be an option.

How do I get `n` threads to run the main function individually using its own Firefox web driver?

Comment: There is a possibility to open 10 links each in separate `Firefox` tab. Do you search for this or you really want to manage 10 browser sessions within same script?

Comment: I do, because I am using back connected/rotating proxies

Comment: Well if you really want to do that, create `driver` in `main()` so that each thread uses a different instance

Answer (score 6):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41354472/multi-threading-in-selenium-python) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30808606/can-selenium-use-multi-threading-in-one-browser) previous question, selenium **is not thread safe**.

You should create drivers inside your main, so that every thread has its own driver.

```
import threading

def rand_function1():
  #random actions

def rand_function2():
  #random actions

def main()
  # use a different driver for each thread
  driver = webdriver.Firefox()
  rand_function1
  rand_function2
  return


if __name__ == '__main__':
    url_list = "https://www.rand_urls.com/"
    for t in range(10):
        t = threading.Thread(target=main)
        t.start()
```