# Selenium Webdriver drive two browser

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to run two distinct actions in two differents browser.

With
 [Is Selenium WebDriver thread safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28093347/is-selenium-webdriver-thread-safe) i have learned an important thing: "You /can/ on the other hand instantiate one WebDriver instance for each thread. "

So i have created two thread who instantiate two drivers (first for google, second for yahoo) like this :

```
public class Thread2 extends Thread{

@Override
public void run() {
    File file = new File(Thread2.class.getClassLoader().getResource("chromedriver").getPath());
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", file.getPath());
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.yahoo.com");
    while (true) {
        driver.findElement(By.id("uh-search-box")).sendKeys("test");
    }
}
```

My Main Class just implementing those two thread and call run function.

There is a way to get two or X browsers running at the same time and excecuting differents task ?

Regards.

More informations at https://github.com/AMimicD/TestSeleniumThread

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to created two different driver variables?

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("http://www.yahoo.com");
WebDriver driver2 = new ChromeDriver();
driver2.get("http://www.whateveryouwant.com");
```

Comment: Absolutely, my drivers were implemented in my thread.
I have two different thread classes (one thread for google and an other for Yahoo) so i'm don't using the same driver variable.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to run your test parallely at the same time. So, in your main method, replace

```
t1.run(); 
t2.run();
```

with

```
t1.start(); 
t2.start();
```

Now you should see both your browsers running at the same time.

`Thread.start()` is required to actually create a new thread so that the runnable's `run` method is executed in parallel.

**Note**: There is a problem with your `while` condition. The condition is always `true` and hence it will be an `infinite loop`. Please fix this in your code.

Comment: Hello and thank you for your answer !
with Thread.start(), i can see those two browsers running at the same time.

No problem for the infinite loop it's absolutely not the definitive usage of my thread !

Comment: Okay..Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Integrate your script with TestNG. It will help you to run your script in parallel mode.

Please Refer [link](http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/testng-multi-browser-cross-browser/) to know more about Parallel execution with TestNG.

Thanks!