# Parallelizing Selenium tests and being thread safe

Tags: c#, selenium, thread-safety

I am trying to parallelize my Selenium tests. I discovered that [Selenium's IWebDriver is not thread safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28093347/is-selenium-webdriver-thread-safe). I don't know if there are serious dangers to not having thread safe tests, but I'd like to try to account for any "bad practices" in any case. In my code, I am  using the following design.

```
public abstract class Parent
{
    public IWebDriver driver;
    public Parent(IWebDriver driver) { this.driver = driver; }
    public bool ElementExists(By by) { 
        if (this.driver.FindElement(by) != null) 
            return true; 
        return false;
    }
}

public class Child1 : Parent 
{
    public Child1(IWebDriver driver) : base(driver) { }
}

public class Child2 : Parent 
{
    public Child2(IWebDriver driver) : base(driver) { }
}
```

Is this code thread safe?

To my understanding, since I am passing in a IWebDriver instance to the constructor, I need not worry about the child classes erroneously using the same IWebDriver. However, just from looking at examples of non-thread safe code, having the IWebDriver field in the abstract Parent class is a concern.

Comment: As long as you are initializing and tearing down a `WebDriver` instance for every test case you run, your code should be thread safe. The issue arises when using the same WebDriver instance for multiple tests, which is bad practice even without parallel.

Comment: @Christine got it. Yes, I'm creating new `WebDriver` instances in each of my `[TestMethod]`s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, if you are setting up and tearing down a `WebDriver` instance before and after each test case -- as opposed to using the same `WebDriver` instance for multiple tests -- then you are already practicing thread safety. This is implied in [Selenium docs](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#q-is-webdriver-thread-safe) on thread-safety.

If you do wish to use multi-threaded WebDriver instances (i.e. multiple tests run on multiple drivers through threading) then you can use the `ThreadLocal` class:

```
public static ThreadLocal<IWebDriver> driver =
    new ThreadLocal<IWebDriver>(() =>
    {
        return new ChromeDriver();
    });
```

`ThreadLocal` is the C# way of practicing thread-safe coding, for any object, not just WebDriver. You can use `Dispose()` method to release resources, and access `WebDriver` instance using `threadLocalDriver.Value`.

You can declare & instantiate the `ThreadLocal` driver in your `[SetUp]` class that runs before every test.